# keep settings in database

Tags: database, django, settings

In a reusable application (in which i don't want to change any code) i would like to change a SETTING var that the application uses (in its forms and maybe other parts) to be dynamic (update its contents from a db table).

What would be the best approach to do that (a middleware maybe?) ?

Comment: I just found http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1099/ which seems it might help in my case ? but any idea how this works ? i'm not familiar with threading module...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into the [django-dbsettings](http://code.google.com/p/django-values/) project.

Comment: although it is a nice app, that wouldn't actually solve the part of not changing code of the reusable application, i want to keep compatibility with django.config.settings

Answer (score 5):

[Django-settings](https://github.com/jqb/django-settings) is another alternative.

It was created about a year after this question was originally asked.

Answer (score 3):

[Here is a grid of multiple such projects](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/live-setting/).