# Django models: Only permit one entry in a model?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to make some of my Django global settings configurable through the admin interface.

To that end, I've decided to set them as database fields, rather than in `settings.py`.

These are the settings I care about:

```
 class ManagementEmail(models.Model):
    librarian_email = models.EmailField()
    intro_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    signoff_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

These are one-off global settings, so I only ever want there to be a single `librarian_email`, `intro_text` etc floating around the system.

Is there a way I can prevent admin users from adding new records here, **without preventing them from editing the existing record**?

I guess I can do this by writing a custom admin template for this model, but I'd like to know if there's a neater way to configure this.

Could I use something other than `class`, for example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please see [this question on "keep[ing] settings in database"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394126/keep-settings-in-database), where the answer seems to be [django-dbsettings](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=y6M&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=django-dbsettings&aq=f&aqi=&aql=f&oq=)

## Update

Just thought of another option: you can create the following model:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

class ManagementEmail(models.Model):
    site = models.OneToOneField(Site)
    librarian_email = models.EmailField()
    intro_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    signoff_text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

Because of the `OneToOneField` field, you can only have one ManagementEmail record per site. Then, just make sure you're using sites and then you can pull the settings thusly:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
managementemail = Site.objects.get_current().managementemail
```

Note that what everyone else is telling you is true; if your goal is to store settings, adding them one by one as fields to a model is not the best implementation. Adding settings over time is going to be a headache: you have to add the field to your model, update the database structure, and modify the code that is calling that setting.

That's why I'd recommend using the django app I mentioned above, since it does exactly what you want -- provide for user-editable settings -- without making you do any extra, unnecessary work.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit wary of django-dbsettings, given the comment from the developer here: http://www.chicagodjango.com/blog/django-settings-database/

Comment: Sounds like his complaints about django-dbsettings wouldn't apply in your case. You are defining all of the settings in the code. I'd definitely recommend against writing your own Singleton to handle this.

Comment: It's the comment from the dev saying that he's no longer maintaining it that worried me. Indeed, when I tried to install it, I started getting errors about `newforms`, suggesting it's pretty out of date... will try your alternative suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 16):

I think the easiest way you can do this is using has_add_permissions function of the ModelAdmin:

```
class ContactUsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ContactUsForm

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False if self.model.objects.count() > 0 else super().has_add_permission(request)
```

You can set the above to be any number you like, see the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/).

If you need more granularity than that, and make the class a singleton at the model level, see [django-solo](https://github.com/lazybird/django-solo). There are many singleton implementations also that I came across.

For StackedInline, you can use max_num = 1.

Comment: I think `return False if self.model.objects.count() > 0 else super().has_add_permission(request)` would be better about respect to permission management rules.

Comment: There is an error if you delete the single entry, this works better               `if self.model.objects.count() > 0:
   return False
  else:
   return True`

Comment: If it returns 0, it will evaluate `super().has_add_permission(request)` and return error if no permission, that sounds right.

Answer (score 4):

Try django-constance. 
Here are some useful links:

https://github.com/jezdez/django-constance

http://django-constance.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Other libraries mentioned in this question seem like they are no longer supported but as of this comment, Constance is still going strong.

Answer (score 3):

I'd take a page out of wordpress and create a Model that support settings.

```
class Settings(models.Model):
    option_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    option_value = models.CharField(max_length=25000)
    option_meta = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

Then you can just pickle (serialize) objects into the fields and you'll be solid.

Build a little api, and you can be as crafty as wordpress and call. `AdminOptions.get_option(opt_name)`

Then you can just load the custom settings into the runtime, keeping the `settings.py` module separate, but equal. A good place to write this would be in an `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 2):

Just set up an `GlobalSettings` app or something with a Key and Value field.

You could easily prevent admin users from changing values by not giving them permission to edit the GlobalSettings app.

```
class GlobalSettingsManager(models.Manager):
      def get_setting(self, key):
          try:
              setting = GlobalSettings.objects.get(key=key)
          except:
              raise MyExceptionOrWhatever
          return setting

class GlobalSettings(models.Model):
      key = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
      value = models.CharField(max_length=255)

      objects = GlobalSettingsManager()

>>> APP_SETTING = GlobalSettings.objects.get_setting('APP_SETTING')
```

There are apps for this but I prefer looking at them and writing my own.

Comment: Yes, I'd also prefer something in the db rather than an app. HOWEVER: as noted in the question, the admin user *should be able to edit* the existing fields - just not able to add new items. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent users from adding/deleting an object by overriding this method on your admin class:

[ModelAdmin.has_add_permission(self, request)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_add_permission)

[ModelAdmin.has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_delete_permission)

Answer (score 0):

Modification of @radtek answer to prevent deleting if only one entry is left

```
class SendgridEmailQuotaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('quota','used')
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False if self.model.objects.count() > 0 else True
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False if self.model.objects.count() <= 1 else True
    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(SendgridEmailQuotaAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
        if(self.model.objects.count() <= 1):
            del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions
```

Answer (score 0):

I had basically the same problem as the original poster describes, and it's easily fixed by overriding modelAdmin classes.  Something similar to this in an admin.py file easily prevents adding a new object but allows editing the current one:

```
class TitleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=TestModel.title):
        return False

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=TestModel.title):
        return True
```

This doesn't prevent a user from posting a form that edits data, but keeps things from happening in the Admin site.  Depending on whether or not you feel it's necessary for your needs you can enable deletion and addition of a record with a minimum of coding.