# Have only one instance of a django model

Tags: django, django-models

I want only one instance of the model below.
How can I enforce this in code?

```
class Employer(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name = "Employer's Name")
    pin =models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name ="Employer's PIN")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: "one instance of the model" means that only 1 Employer would be created in the entire DB?

Comment: are you interested in having unique employer names and pins? in which case you can add `unique` to the CharField.

Comment: Yes. I want to be able to create only one employer who can however be editable.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888159/django-models-only-permit-one-entry-in-a-model

Comment: Hope it helps -- I had a need for a general "settings" model (that I'd only have one of) and just ended up giving my model a OneToOne relationship with Site, as described in that link.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
class Employer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Employer's Name")
    pin = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Employer's PIN")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'pin')
```

from [Django Model Meta options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together).

Comment: That's not really what the question asks.