# How to handle project or app specific settings in django?

Tags: django

How can one store, retrieve and allow the user to change the settings of a project or an app? A constant in settings.py is not good enough, as I want some users to be able to change the value of the setting. A way to present these in the admin interface would be optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's via an admin interface then using the database sounds like a sure bet. Check out this [similar looking question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394126/keep-settings-in-database) on StackOverflow.

Comment: Do you mean using a model with each setting as a field? Isn't it somewhat of an overkill?

Comment: If it was me I'd do a model that looks like:
`user_id | key | value` and then whenever a user customises something I'd add a row in there.

Comment: I think that saving each value as a string doesn't provide type safety, so I probably gonna go with the a field per setting or make a simple app. Thanks!